# best way to create an operator+ inside a class without declaring so many unnecessary variables

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, operators

So we were given a question where we have a class called Cocktail with name and volume attributes. Now they want us to "write an overloading operator addition to make the mix of two cocktails i.e. add two cocktails together which gives : 
volume of cocktail 1 + volume of cocktail 2  is the resultant volume and name of cocktail 1 + "mixed with " + name of cocktail 2 as the resultant name. 
They said make all the necessary hypothesis of the class Cocktail .(i supposed there are private attributes name and volume. )There is not however yet any other overloaded function in the class Cocktail. 
Does that mean i am allowed to define two operators?
Because i was thinking of creating an internal operator += and then calling it in my external operator+ which would be the most logical solution in my opinion:

```
//inside my class Cocktail, INTERNAL OPERATOR
Cocktail& operator+=(Cocktail const& c1){
    name = name + "mixed with" + c1.name; 
    volume = volume + c1.volume; 
    return *this; 
}

//external operator

const Cocktail operator+(Cocktail c1, Cocktail const& c2){
    c1+=c2; 
    return c1; 
}
```

but i dont know if with their instructions i would be allowed to make two. So i tried to make one internal operator and the only thing i could think of is having to declare a new cocktail inside the definition and then returning its value as follows:

```
//internal operator

Cocktail operator+(Cocktail const& other) const {
   Cocktail c; 
   c.name = name + "mixed with" + other.name; 
   c.volume = volume + other.volume; 
   return c; 
}
```

but i find that kind of weird, so i thought maybe this would be better but im starting to question if my next option would compile:

```
//internal operator
Cocktail& operator+(Cocktail const& c){
    name = name + "mixed with" + c.name; 
    volume = volume + c.volume; 
    return *this; 
}
```

do i have the right to do that`?
which is the best way to define an operator? 
is there a better way?
thanks

Comment: When you mix your cocktails, do you pour them into a new glass? IMHO that would correspond to the external  `operator+` and should leave `c1` untouched. If, however, you put the second cocktail into the first it corresponds to the internal `operator+=` which modifies `c1`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
   Cocktail operator+(Cocktail const& other) const {
      Cocktail c; 
      c.name = name + "mixed with" + other.name; 
      c.volume = volume + other.volume; 
      return c; 
   }
```

This is the right way to implement the binary + operator. Think as: You create a new cocktail out of two others.

If you want to add a cocktail to another one, the operator += would be correct.

But based on your task I guess the first one would be better.

Comment: That is *a valid way* to do it, but "the right way" might be too bold a statement.  `Cocktail operator+(Cocktail c1, Cocktail const& c2)` would apply the same implicit conversion rules to both operands **and** support more C++11 move semantics.

Comment: Ok the best way from the choices inside the question. And the most common signature that is used (e.g. for basic arithmetic purposes).

Comment: @DrewDormann: My bad. I thought he had to use an internal operator (given by the task). An external operator makes more sense if the members are accessible.

Comment: I would have defined the `operator+` in terms of the `operator+=` to prevent duplicated code. So "the right way" does not seem to be universal "right way".

Comment: Code reuse in this case leads to IMHO unwanted and unexpected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Prefer this approach.

```
const Cocktail operator+(Cocktail c1, Cocktail const& c2){
    return c1+=c2; 
}
```

- It does not duplicate code.
- It allows the same implicit conversions for `c1` and `c2`.  (`*this` doesn't implicitly convert)
- It allows move semantics or copy elision for `c1`
- It allows better encapsulation